# Typescript: Why Partial Utility Type doesn't work on Indexed Access Types

Tags: typescript

When using `Partial` on indexed access type, it doesn't set the properties to optional:

e.g.

```js
class Klass {
    prop = {
        a: true,
        b: 42, 
    };

    func() {
        let val: Partial<typeof this["prop"]>;
        val = {a: false}; // error: Type '{ a: false; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<this["prop"]>'.
        val = {a: false, b: 13}; // ok
    }
}
```

(see in [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/MYGwhgzhAEDS5WgbwFDXdADgJwPaegF5k0MywAuaAF2wFcBTAGlLPQCMqAWAJielbQAvgG4UggGZ0AdsAAUAShJsMIBtWgA3MCCoAFMNmoBLHQB5qAT0wNcEmgAtjEANoAiHPjcBdAHxiVdG0QImRKaAkdCAZRaAB6OOgGbDxsKgAVawZoAHIkaHDIkGiRYRzoZ2hpXA1ICGMAc2kwdjUaXBos3IMjUxALJ1cPPEwfXxyAOkEyYNCkQqjmaE5oAEYAZliE6FwAa0EhFEOgA))

my use case is something like:

```js
class Base {
    setState(s: Partial<typeof this["state"]>){}
}

class Subclass extends Base {
    state = {
        a: true,
        b: 42,  
    };

    func() {
        this.setState({a: false});
    }
}
```

why is this not working and how can i get it to work?

Comment: `this` is actually a very different type from `Klass`.

Comment: @catgirlkelly, could you please explain what do you mean?

Comment: If your question is "Why doesn't this work", see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36505 for the closest to an authoritative answer to "why", as your title asks.  Your subclasses might *narrow* the `a` property, in which case `{a: false}` is not necessarily assignable... like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOPjrN).  So it fails for soundness reasons.  But the fact that `{a: false, b: 13}` works is weird.  The issue linked above is marked "needs investigation", so I don't think anyone knows for certain.

Comment: If your question is "how can I get it to work", that depends very much on what you're really trying to do.  Presumably you could just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and move on.  Or you could make it `Klass` instead of `this`.  If you have use cases for `this`, you should probably show them (e.g., a demo subclass and why it matters).

Comment: Please consider clarifying whether you are primarily asking "why is it not working" or whether you're primarily asking "how can I get it to work"?  The questions are related, but distinct.

Comment: Hi @jcalz, thanx for the github links. the issues seems similar. so basically using  `this` is the problem here? I've updated my question with the use case i have for a base class needing the info from a subclass .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the name of the class and access `prop` without using this:

```js
let val: Partial<Klass["prop"]>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/MYGwhgzhAEDS5WgbwFDXdADgJwPaegF5k0MywAuaAF2wFcBTAGlLPQCMqAWAJielbQAvgG4UggGZ0AdsAAUAShJsMIBtWgA3MCCoAFMNmoBLHQB54kCAG0ARDny2AugD4xK9NpBFklaBJ0IBlFoAHpQ6AZsPGwqABUAT0wGaAByJGg-AJAgkWFU6GMYaVwNK2MAc2kwdjUaXBoklNSDI1MQM2oACyK7B0xnF1SAOkEyLx8kLMDmaE5oAEYAZhDw6FwAa0EhFB2UaiboOIYIDWJWk3NLKD68AdcUIA)

Comment: but it is meant to be used in a base class. basically: ```
class Base {
  func(){
    let val: Partial<typeof this["prop"]>;
  }
}
class Sub extends Base {
  prop = {
        a: true,
        b: 42, 
    };
}```

Comment: @mbehzad You could define prop in the base class and use what Tobias mentioned: [Example Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ0PQgFzNpAvCgL7qYQLYDKu+AFBAFzQAKYATtgJZggA88CgG0ARDjwIRAXQB8ASjSYl0APQro2ABZcIAOnH5oRZLtNad+2ggA00U-uIBuMsugB5AEYArBMGy7ICC4AcwA7OnM9AxssOWclUlJUUEDoKgBXDxSoaAQAD3xQgBMYQSRFcisjFBdlMGZsdnSbWqUPZgAWACZbaFqnVFqAM3TQ4Do5GtcMSP1KGgk6ZHroId4KYjj+1CTgAHtQnGg96tCEAHc0zOyICec93RGxieSDiD2QBF0QPeC6B+iciAA) Not sure if I got what you need though.

Comment: @ChristianTapia, I added an example to the question regarding what my actual use case is. basically there is some functionality that the base class provides, and then there are subclasses which each have their properties. something like reacts React.Component and the regular componets inheriting it. if that makes sense